# Get bool return value when checking if smb1 is enabled using powershell

Tags: powershell, server-message-block

I can use 
`Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB2Protocol`

to get table style result:

[image]

How can I get bool result which in this case would be `False`

I'm working on DSC, and currently working on SMB script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother piping to `Select-Object` if you just want to read the property value. The object returned from `Get-SmbServerConfiguration` has it already.

```
$smbConfig = Get-SmbServerConfiguration
$smbConfig.EnableSMB2Protocol

False
```

Or shorthand as `(Get-SmbServerConfiguration).EnableSMB2Protocol`